# C++ invalid pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, free

I'm trying to solve this problem : https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/trees/binary-and-nary-trees/practice-problems/algorithm/comrades-ii-6/

I'm pretty sure the algorithm is right, but I'm getting invalid pointer errors in the submissions.
I've been trying to find the error, but to no end.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int value;
    vector<struct node*> children;
};

void handshakes(int n, struct node *node, long long int &hs, long long int &fb, int height){
    if((int)node->children.size() == 0){
        hs += height-1;
        fb += n - height;
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)node->children.size(); i++){
            handshakes(n, node->children[i], hs, fb, height+1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;

        for(int t = 0; t < T; t++){
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        vector<struct node*> army;
        army.resize(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++){
            struct node *temp = (node * )malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->value = i;
            temp->children.resize(0);
            army.push_back(temp);
        }

        int a;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            cin >> a;

            for(int j = 0; j < (int)army.size(); j++){
                if(army[j]->value == i+1){
                    army[a]->children.push_back(army[j]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        long long int hs = 0;
        long long int fb = 0;
        handshakes(n, army[0], hs, fb, 0);
        cout << hs << " " << fb/2 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me. I'm getting kind of frustrated.

EDIT: The error seems to occur when n is large.

Comment: whats an 'invalid pointer error'?

Comment: My advice is develop this on a system with an IDE and use your debugger.

Comment: What's the point of `resize(0)` right after creating a vector?!

Comment: @Arash Where do you think he creates a vector?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `vector<struct node*> army;`

Comment: @Arash That's where he declares it. Where do you think he constructs/creates it? (See my answer. He doesn't.)

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize `C++` objects so it won't work for complex types like `std::vector`, you should use `new` (or in-place construct).

Comment: *I've been trying to find the error, but to no end.* -- Which goes to show that just  doing "hackerrank" questions doesn't teach you basic C++.  The obvious error is that you're using `malloc`, something you should never had even thought about using if you are learning C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How would you suggest I learn C++?

Comment: By reading peer-reviewed C++ books.  C++ isn't one of those languages where you can learn by just "winging it".

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++){
    struct node *temp = (node * )malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->value = i;
    temp->children.resize(0);
```

You never constructed `temp->children` so you have no `vector` object on which to call `resize`. The obvious fix is to change `malloc` to `new`.

Comment: I'm learning C++ by myself and I guess I need to read some more formal rigorous stuff. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what you already know. But definitely don't bother learning pre-C++11. Learn stuff like `unique_ptr` and learn RAII.